# Problems with cookies in scrapy - IP blocked

Tags: python, python-2.7, cookies, amazon-ec2, scrapy

I'm new to scrapy (it is my first time), and I'm facing some problems. The whole idea is to scrap data from a website and store it on a Sqlite database, using python.

I got blocked out while scrapping data, using scrapy in Python 2.7. I'm having this problem and only changing the IP is not working, so I would like to know how can I delete the cookies used by scrapy to a new fresh new run in another computer (IP address).

The scraper was working fine, but I made too many requests (my bad), and now the website blocked me. I tried to use scrapy-polipo-tor and after scrapoxy, no success there. So I decided to up a AWS ec2 instance and run from it, since it would have a different IP address. I was even using a Windows instance (I have mac OSX running here). The problem is I keep getting redirected to the page where the website says I'm blocked, even using a different IP.

My `settings.py` is like:

```
BOT_NAME = 'ScrapMSOMJournal'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['ScrapMSOMJournal.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'ScrapMSOMJournal.spiders'

# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False

CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 1
RETRY_TIMES = 0
COOKIES_ENABLED = False
```

My `spider.py`is as follow: (not actual file name)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from scrapy import Request, Spider


    class PaperInfoSpider(Spider):
        name = "infos"

        with open("/Users/pedroveronezi/BIA656_PaperProbability/links_ids.txt", "rt") as f:
            start_urls = [url.strip() for url in f.readlines()]
        # start_urls = [
        #     'http://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/abs/10.1287/msom.2014.0498',
        # ]

        custom_settings = {
            'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY=False': False,
            'ITEM_PIPELINES': {
                'ScrapMSOMJournal.pipelines.SQLiteStorePipelineInfos': 300,
            },
            'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 40000.0,
            'COOKIES_ENABLED': False,
        }

        # response.css('.tocArticleDoi a::text')[0].extract()
        def parse(self, response):
            authors = []
            for paper in response.css('.contribDegrees'):
                authors.append(paper.css('.header::text').extract_first())
            affiliations = []
            for paper in response.css('.contribAff::text'):
                affiliations.append(paper.extract())
            dates_received = []
            dates_accepted = []
            dates_published = []
            for paper in response.css('.dates'):
                temp = paper.css('div::text').extract_first()
                temp = str(temp)
                start_rec = temp.find('Received:')
                received_date = temp[start_rec:].split('\n')[0]
                start_acc = temp.find('Accepted:')
                accepted_date = temp[start_acc:].split('\n')[0]
                start_pub = temp.find('Published Online:')
                published_date = temp[start_pub:].split('\n')[0]
                if start_rec != -1:
                    dates_received.append(str(received_date))
                elif start_acc != -1:
                    dates_accepted.append(str(accepted_date))
                elif start_pub != -1:
                    dates_published.append(str(published_date))

            keywords = []
            for paper in response.css('.abstractKeywords , .abstractKeywords .title'):
                keywords.append(paper.css('a::text').extract())
            title = str(response.css('.chaptertitle::text').extract_first())
            title = title.split()
            title = ' '.join(title)

            try:
                abstract = str(response.css('.abstractInFull p::text').extract_first())
            except UnicodeEncodeError:
                abstract = ''

            keywords_string = []
            for key in keywords:
                keywords_string.append('|'.join(key))

            link_complete = str(response.css('.publicationContentDoi a::text').extract_first())
            temp = link_complete.split('/')
            link_id = str(temp[len(temp)-1])

            keywords_string = '|'.join(keywords_string)
            date_received = ''
            for date in dates_received:
                date_received = str(date).split(':')[1]
            date_accepted = ''
            for date in dates_accepted:
                date_accepted = str(date).split(':')[1]
            date_published = ''
            for date in dates_published:
                date_published = str(date).split(':')[1]

            dict_rtn = {'authors': '|'.join(authors),
                        'affiliations': '|'.join(affiliations),
                        'keywords': keywords_string,
                        'date_received': date_received,
                        'date_accepted': date_accepted,
                        'date_published': date_published,
                        'title': title,
                        'abstract': abstract,
                        'link_id': link_id,
                        }
            return dict_rtn
```

In whatever computer I use I keep getting the same output message:

```
2017-03-20 19:38:55 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.3.0 started (bot: ScrapMSOMJournal)
2017-03-20 19:38:55 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'ScrapMSOMJournal.spiders', 'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN': 1, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['ScrapMSOMJournal.spiders'], 'RETRY_TIMES': 0, 'BOT_NAME': 'ScrapMSOMJournal', 'COOKIES_ENABLED': False}
2017-03-20 19:38:55 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
2017-03-20 19:38:55 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2017-03-20 19:38:55 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2017-03-20 19:38:55 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
['ScrapMSOMJournal.pipelines.SQLiteStorePipelineInfos']
2017-03-20 19:38:55 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-03-20 19:38:55 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-03-20 19:38:55 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2017-03-20 19:38:56 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/abs/10.1287/msom.2015.0518?cookieSet=1> from <GET http://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/abs/10.1287/msom.2015.0518>
```

Comment: You can try disabling redirects. See [scrapy doc](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#redirect-enabled)

Comment: Hello @Granitosaurus, I tried it did not work. It disable the redirects but doesn't crawl the info.

Comment: Thanks @KlausD., I appreciate the input, as I said, I'm new to crawling web, so I didn't even know that I could be blocked, and I have/had no intention of overflowing the website with requests.

Comment: Don't worry, you won't overflow the website. Were you able to connect to any of the urls at all? maybe they are down in general?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not really a technical question. It is wholly inappropriate to ask for assistance avoiding detection while continuing to engage in  behavior that prompted the block the first time.  If it's not your site then you have no right to access it in a manner inconsistent with the site's acceptable use policy.  **If you disagree with efforts to block you, your solution is to contact the site and negotiate a mutually agreeable arrangement.**

Answer (score 0):

Try changing user_agent, see [docs](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#user-agent) for how to do that in scrapy.
By default scrapy uses something like "scrapy v1.3" as it's user_agent string and it's easily detectable.

And checkout official mozzila's page on user agent string [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent/Firefox)

in short, try setting this in your `setting.py`:

```
USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT x.y; Win64; x64; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0"
```